# Codificacion de UTF-8 spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mariadb

Estoy usando spring y cuando mando a llamar el servicio me devuelve con caracteres que no son.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregue en el clase controller.impl de la siguiente manera

```
@PostMapping(value = "/findByCriteria", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

y en la base de datos si vienen los campos con sus acentos, mi gestor es MariaDB
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo le hago para que se muestren mis datos con sus respectivos acentos?

Comment: Mira este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc Parece ser algo similar a tu problema :) Suerte!

Comment: ¿Los datos en tu base de datos están usando la misma codificación?

Comment: Esta en utf8mb4 hay otra codificación a eso? Saludos

Comment: Ya hice justamente lo que aparece en el link rockardmigu3 y aún me sigue devolviendo los caracteres que no son

Comment: Que raro, `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` deberia de ser suficiente. Que serializador estas usando, y como esta implementado?

Comment: @FranciscoFigueroa como estas obteniendo los datos, agrega a tu pregunta por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando con DBeaver resulta que sí estaba mal la base de datos, el problema del encoding era en la base de datos, lo que no entiendo es porque en consola si los mostraba con sus respectivos acentos y en DBeaver ya los mostraba como me aparecía en la respuesta del JSON, muestro la evidencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]